# Retrieving model data from view to controller c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, viewmodel

I know there are many similar questions here in SOF, but I have looked at all the solutions and tried them, but could not make it work.

Here's the issue: I have a controller method that passes a Viewmodel to view (strongly-typed). In View, I have a textbox in Webgrid such that whenever its value changes, it posts back to a different controller method. The issue is that I am unable to retrieve the Viewmodel data that I had earlier passed, in the second controller method.

Below is the code:

## Controller Action method 1:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    PlanViewModel myPlan = new PlanViewModel();
    /*Do some stuff to populate myPlan object*/
    return View("PlanIndex", myPlan);
}
```

## View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PlanIndex";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using myproject.ViewModels
@model myproject.ViewModels.PlanViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateUnits", "Plan", FormMethod.Post))
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.snack, canSort: false, canPage: false);
    int rowNum = 0;
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml(columns:
         grid.Columns
         (
             grid.Column("Sr", format: item => rowNum = rowNum + 1),
             grid.Column("Unit", format: item => Html.TextBox("FoodList[" + (rowNum - 1).ToString() + "].Unit", (object)item.unit, new { onchange = "submit();" })),
             grid.Column("Name", format: (item) => Html.TextBox("FoodList[" + (rowNum - 1).ToString() + "].Name", (object)item.name)),
             grid.Column("Serving", format: (item) => Html.TextBox("FoodList[" + (rowNum - 1).ToString() + "].Serving", (object)item.serving)),
             grid.Column("Serving Unit", format: (item) => Html.TextBox("FoodList[" + (rowNum - 1).ToString() + "].ServingUnit", (object)item.servingUnit)),
             grid.Column("Protein", format: (item) => Html.TextBox("FoodList[" + (rowNum - 1).ToString() + "].Protein", (object)item.protein))
         ), mode: WebGridPagerModes.Numeric)
    </div>
}
```

Note that in the above view there is a textbox for "Unit" which has postback attached on value change. If the value changes, a call is made to UpdateUnits action method.

## Controller Action method 2 (UpdateUnits):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateUnits(PlanViewModel model)
{
    int updatedUnit = model.unit;
    /*Some additional complex logic*/
    return View("PlanIndex", model);
}
```

In this second controller method, model is always null. I do not want to repopulate complete model again and again each time user changes value in textbox. Note that my Viewmodel consists of multiple Lists of custom classes and other int, float declarations.

I feel there is some basic thing that I am missing, but being new to MVC, I am unable to figure out.

## ViewModel class

```
    public class PlanViewModel
    {
        public List<Food> breakfast { get; set; }
        public List<Food> lunch { get; set; }
        public List<Food> snack { get; set; }
        public List<Food> dinner { get; set; }
        public Goal goal { get; set; }
        public int totalProtein { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Thanks for edit @StephenMuecke. Will keep in mind :)

Comment: You need to show your model (does it have a collection property named `FoodList`?)

Comment: Don't know WebGrid does it do validation? Maybe check ModelState.Isvalid first?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Added my viewmodel. It does not have FoodList property. FoodList is just used to create an array of textboxes in my Webgrid to be used back in controller for edit/delete operations.

Comment: You creating `name` attributes that have no relationship at all to your model, therefore will not bind. Not clear what your wanting to edit, but if you expect to bind to the collection of `List<Food> snack`, then you need to generate `name="snack[0].somePropertyOfFood"`, `name="snack[1].somePropertyOfFood"` etc

Comment: @HenryRoeland I just checked. ModelState.IsValid comes true, but the model is retrieved null.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried changing FoodList to snack and code was able to bind values. However, only those values got bound which were used as controls in the view. There are 15 properties in Food class, but only 5 which are used in Webgrid were returned. Other properties were all defaulted. Is there a way to get complete Viewmodel data as it was passed?

Comment: No, not unless you were to generate a form control for each property. But why would you want to. Just get the data again in the POST method. And you should be using a view model for `Food` (not the data model). View models should not contain properties which are data models, especially when editing

Comment: @StephenMuecke Basically when I first populate the myPlan object in Index action method, I am using Random generator class to randomly pick some data and populate. So if I have apple, orange and banana, Index will randomly select say apple and pass it to view. View shows the nutritional values of apples. On view, user can change the number of units of apples which should also update the total nutritional info. If on postback I again call the Index method, it will again randomize and might select orange this time.